# Alternative to Ruby String.dump that doesn't escape printable characters like double quotes (Ruby 1.8.7)

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby string that can sometimes contain some non-printable characters. Before I show it in the GUI I use `String.dump` to convert the string to user readable format. The side effect is that it also escapes double quotes. Is there an easy way to avoid that or only `dump` the string if it has any non-printable characters?

```
irb(main):041:0> s = "a=b,\"c=d\""
=> "a=b,\"c=d\""
irb(main):042:0> s.dump
=> "\"a=b,\\\"c=d\\\"\""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for non-printable chars (or gsub them) with this regexp:

```
/[^[:print:]]/
```